# On Raspberry Pi 4 are "FROM" base images golang:latest and arm32v7/golang:latest any different?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If I wish to create a Go binary in a Docker image to be run as a container on a Raspberry Pi 4 (whose architecture is 32-bit ARM AFAIK), which base image is recommended to be used?

- FROM golang:latest
- FROM arm32v7/golang:latest

In fact will there be any difference, or will Docker be clever enough to know that the first should really be the second on a 32-bit ARM architecture?

(I know the second choice works, and I think the first also does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These images are the same. You can check hash of each image and see that they are equal: `6ab6b95325d8` ([golang:latest](https://hub.docker.com/layers/golang/library/golang/latest/images/sha256-6ab6b95325d829585d9aecf20e4d04aea14fc14a5d3420da767e81f65f0da832?context=explore), [arm32v7/golang:latest](https://hub.docker.com/layers/arm32v7/golang/latest/images/sha256-6ab6b95325d829585d9aecf20e4d04aea14fc14a5d3420da767e81f65f0da832?context=explore)). I will prefer to use generic `golang:latest`, because it will allow to build new image on different platform without changes to `Dockerfile`.

Note from `arm32v7/golang:latest`:

> this is the "per-architecture" repository for the arm32v7 builds of **the golang official image**